# powershell quits before conversion done

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write an automated conversion powershell script to convert las files with potreeconverter.
Here is my script

```
$ToBeConvertedFolders = 'D:\potree_converter\ToBeConvertedFolders\TestExport1.0'
$ApacheHtdocsFolder = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\projets\'
$InputFormat = 'las'
$PotreeConverter = 'D:\potree_converter\potreeconverter.exe'
Get-ChildItem "$ToBeConvertedFolders\LAS\*.$InputFormat" |
ForEach-Object {
    $Filename = $_.BaseName
    $InputPath = "`"$ToBeConvertedFolders\$Filename.$InputFormat`""
    $OutputPath = "`"$ApacheHtdocsFolder\$Filename`""
    Start-Process $PotreeConverter -ArgumentList "$InputPath -o $OutputPath --page-template 
    c:\potree_converter\resources\page_template\  --generate-page $Filename --title TITILE HERE" -wait
}
```

Script runs fine and start to process the las file and I have the html output file but it quits without completing the conversion process.

Could you please suggest anything to solve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Does potreeconverter.exe work on its own, if you just type the command directly into a console ? Your script looks fine to me, I'd blame this software.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. When I type the command directly on console it works fine.

Comment: Did you paste the script correctly? It looks like the Start-Process line stops at `--page-template ` and the rest is on a separate line. If that's the case in your script the `-Wait` parameter is never seen by `Start-Process` which means the script closes as soon as the final conversion in the script launches.

Comment: Thank for the tip. In the powershell ps1 file the script start process line is not in 2 lines. It's in one line. And the html file generated has the original file name as specified by the variable $Filename. So the script has parsed through $Filename.